# list of list iteration for reading dicom files

Tags: python, iterator

Hello I am trying to read some Dicom files so I can transform them into tensors, I have my files in a nested list

```
 test_value_list= [['/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00019637202178323708467/1.dcm',
  '/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00019637202178323708467/2.dcm'],
 ['/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00015637202177877247924/1.dcm',
  '/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00015637202177877247924/2.dcm'],
 ['/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00012637202177665765362/1.dcm',
  '/content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00012637202177665765362/2.dcm']]
```

I am trying to iterate through the list so I can read the files and save them as tensors

```
def image_tensor_test():
  image_tensor_list=[]
  for i in range(len(test_value_list)):
    for j in range (len(test_value_list[i])):
      
      image_byte_test_first =tf.io.read_file(test_value_list[j][i])
      image_1 = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_byte_test_first, dtype=tf.uint16)
      image_tensor_list.append(image1)
      
  return image_tensor_list

image_tensor_test()
```

and I am getting this error

```
NotFoundError: /content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00015637202177877247924/1.dcm; No such file or directory [Op:ReadFile]
```

I try to add them manually for example:

```
test_value_list[0][0]
```

and it works, if some could help me with this one it would be amazing,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def image_tensor_test():
    image_tensor_list = []
    for file in test_value_list:
        for k in range(0, len(test_value_list)-1):
            image_byte_test_first = tf.io.read_file(file[k])
            image_1 = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_byte_test_first, dtype=tf.uint16)
            image_tensor_list.append(image1)

    return image_tensor_list
```

Comment: it doesnt work i got the same error ` NotFoundError: /content/drive/My Drive/pulmonaryfibrosis/train/ID00015637202177877247924/1.dcm; No such file or directory [Op:ReadFile]` I am wondering if it has somethig to do with the decode method